# 100.toString vs 100['toString']

Tags: javascript

```
100['toString'] //does not fail
100.toString //fails
```

why?

100.toString is not same as 100.toString() . So why in the second case I am not getting the function as returned value?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The second line fails because it is parsed as a number "100.", followed by "toString".

To use the dot notation, Any of the following will work:

```
(100).toString
100.0.toString
100..toString
var a = 100;
a.toString
```

If you are trying to *call* the `toString` function , you will also need to include the parentheses:

```
(100).toString()
100.0.toString()
100..toString()
var a = 100;
a.toString()
```

I prefer using parentheses (or a variable, if I already have one obviously), because the alternatives could be confusing and unintuitive.

Comment: Another example: `100..toString()` works as well since the first period is counted as part of the number, and the second as part of the property access syntax.

Comment: Note that `100` and `100.0` are not the same.

Comment: @Max, good point. It looks kind of funny, but I'll add that too.

Comment: @Gumbo, all numbers in JavaScript are floating point, so they are exactly the same.

Comment: `100 .toString()` ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use `(100).toString` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Parens is the best way to go. You've got the same issue w/ function definitions as well.

```
function () {}.call() => fails
(function () {}).call() => succeeds
```